# Boost converter to 5V

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, converter, boost

I'm searching for a boost converter to convert up small voltage (min 0.5V / max 81mA) to 5V.
(the smaller the better)

Can you recommend a special type number?

Comment: No, as that would be answering a shopping question.  -1 for not having bothered to read the rules before posting.

Comment: Have a look for "power harvesting" ICs.

Answer (score 6):

The nearest I can find is this device: -

[image]

With a 0.5V input it will produce 5V but only with probably 50mA output (Green graph for TPS61202): -

[image]

Hopefully it'll work for your application

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a particular chip that you use to build a circuit, or do you want a ready-built circuit?
Pololu has a ready-build boost converter based on the NCP1402. The NCP1402 is a fine boost controller for low voltage/current, and the Pololu implementation is decent.
http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/798/pictures